# Query and index optimization for a table containing 10 million records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, ssms, index-tuning, query-performance

I was trying to retrieve data from a table A to retrieve data for 1 month, which has around 10 million records and 21 indexes built on it, It took me 3 min to retrieve around 20 columns and total of 300 K records from that table A joined with some other table B which has around 40000 records.

We are using SQL Server 2012 standard edition.

Will like to know how can I improve the query execution time.

Query plan can be found in the below link :

[Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rky3j-9QX)

Server information  :
[Server Info](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1puysrNxNRxeaEaAmvkLhOj8Hd9ZJ6yRI)

Comment: Try posting your query plan and server information per this post: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/ For reference, 10 million rows isn't really a lot to handle on commodity grade hardware - performance can vary a lot with the server and the query, so the more specific you can be, the more helpful of an answer you'll get.

Comment: I think your question is too broad as written. Post your DDL and query for specific help. Indexing often involves trade-offs between maintenance costs and query performance so much depends on your workload and priorities.

Comment: Hi @Brent , posted the query plan and server information.

Comment: Well by the looks of the execution plan you are joining more than just table A with table B. You have a table C, D, E, F and G too. How many rows do those individual tables have?

Comment: @SayantaniNath the server info was clipped out. You're using Amazon RDS, and your server is dangerously underpowered (as noted by the RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE warning.) You're also retrieving >1.5 million rows in the query - I'd take a step back and ask if you're really going to paint 1.5 million rows for the end user to read through. If not, consider writing it to disk rather than trying to bring back 1.5 million rows.

Comment: When you have dates, you always want to work with them as dates. Doing stuff like this will prevent efficient use of any indexes you do create: `where
  (convert(varchar(20),itt.ForwardFeed,23) >= convert(varchar(20),'2018-06-01',23) AND
    convert(VARCHAR(20),itt.ForwardFeed,23) <= convert(VARCHAR(20),'2018-06-30',23))`.

Comment: As you are not using SQL 2016 yet, besides the other suggestions, maybe you should also consider enabling TF 2371. You can check Erik's post here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/changes-to-auto-update-stats-thresholds-in-sql-server-2016/

Comment: Hi @hot2use, A - 10 million , B - 40 K , C - 13 million , D- 800 K, E - 600 K , F-1.5 million are the rows for each individual tables.

Answer (score 2):

The scan of itt is expensive:

[image]

So to take advantage of an index or partition using itt.ForwardFeed,
change

```
    where
      (convert(varchar(20),itt.ForwardFeed,23) >= convert(varchar(20),'2018-06-01',23) 
AND     convert(VARCHAR(20),itt.ForwardFeed,23) <= convert(VARCHAR(20),'2018-06-30',23))
```

to

```
where itt.ForwardFeed >= '2018-06-01'
  AND itt.ForwardFeed <= '2018-06-30'
```

This should work whether itt.ForwardFeed is a Date or a varchar in ODBC Canonical YYYY-MM-DD format.